# How to get each checked checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following:

**PHP/HTML CODE:**

```
<?php
$c = 1;
    foreach($this->contactos as $contacto){
?>
        <div class="uk-form-row">
        <label for="contactopadrino<?php echo $c; ?>" class="uk-form-label"><?php echo $contacto->email; ?></label>

        <input class="contactopadrinos" name="contactopadrino[]" id="contactopadrino<?php echo $c; ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $contacto->email; ?>" />
        </div>

<?php 
$c++;
}
?>
```

**jQuery CODE:**

```
     function validarEnviarDescuento(){  
        $('#errorofertacontainerdescuento').css('display','none');
        $('#errorofertadescuento').html('');
        var validar = 0;
        var vacio = 0;
        for(var e=1; e<6; e++){
            var email = $("#email_contactopadrino"+e).val();    
            if(!validarEmail(email) && email != ''){
                validar++;
            }
            if(email != ''){
                vacio++;
            }
        }

        if(!vacio){
             $('input:radio:checked').each(function () { 
                var $this = $(this);

                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            $('#errorofertadescuento').append('<li>' + '<?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_ERROR_SIN_SELECCIONAR'); ?>' + '</li>');
            $('#errorofertacontainerdescuento').css('display','block');
            return false;
        }
        if(validar){ 
            $('#errorofertadescuento').append('<li>' + '<?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_ERROR_EMAIL_INCORRECTO'); ?>' + '</li>');
            $('#errorofertacontainerdescuento').css('display','block');
            return false; 
        }
        else{ 
            return true; 
        }

 }
```

Im trying to go through each input and if one is checked it should return true and submit but what I have done is not working.

Comment: You don't need `each`. Just `$('input:radio:checked').length` will do

Comment: @Satpal How do I know if one is checked? I did this: `if($('input:radio:checked').length){return true;}` and even if I dont  check any it submits and it shouldnt

Comment: Use `return $('input:radio:checked').length;` It will return `true` if any one is checked else `false`

Comment: @Satpal I need to have it in an if statement

Comment: I think you need to invert your condition. try `if($('input:radio:checked').length == 0){return false;}`

Comment: @Satpal doesnt work :(

Comment: I think you need  `$('input:checkbox:checked')`. I see checkboxes

Comment: @Satpal yea!! that was dumb of us haha. Thanks mate, add it as an answer and I will accept =)

Comment: Posted one, Glad we solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `each`. instead use cobination [**:checked**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and `length`

```
return $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
```

It will return true if anyone of the checkbox button has checked

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) with selector to get all radio buttons those are checked.

```
$('input:radio:checked')
```

> **Description**: Matches all elements that are checked or selected, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

If you want to check if atleast one radio is checked then you can use length

```
if($('input:radio:checked').length)
{
}
```

For iterating through checked radio you can use each

```
$('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
  alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Could you check my post, I put my function and where I need this to work but it seems to not do anything, thanks.

Comment: Replace $('input:radio:checked').each(function () { 
                var $this = $(this);

                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    return true;
                }
            }); by return $('input:radio:checked').length == 0 return false: true;